# url to acces the application installed in websphere application server 9

Tags: websphere

I have installed an application in Websphere application server  9. The admin console url is

mysite.com:10203/ibm/console/secure/securelogon.do

I see the context root of this application is /hello

Can anyone guess what is the entire url for accessing the application. When I tried the below url it is not working

mysite.com:10203/hello

Below are the Host aliases for the virtual hosts

[image]

Below are the list of ports

BOOTSTRAP_ADDRESS
mysite.com
    10204
    No associated transports

CSIV2_SSL_MUTUALAUTH_LISTENER_ADDRESS
mysite.com
    10209
    No associated transports

CSIV2_SSL_SERVERAUTH_LISTENER_ADDRESS
mysite.com
    10208
    No associated transports

DCS_UNICAST_ADDRESS
*
    10211
    View associated transports

IPC_CONNECTOR_ADDRESS
${LOCALHOST_NAME}
    10206
    No associated transports

ORB_LISTENER_ADDRESS
mysite.com
    10210
    No associated transports

OVERLAY_TCP_LISTENER_ADDRESS
*
    10219
    No associated transports

OVERLAY_UDP_LISTENER_ADDRESS
*
    10218
    No associated transports

SAS_SSL_SERVERAUTH_LISTENER_ADDRESS
mysite.com
    10207
    No associated transports

SIB_ENDPOINT_ADDRESS
*
    10212
    View associated transports

SIB_ENDPOINT_SECURE_ADDRESS
*
    10213
    View associated transports

SIB_MQ_ENDPOINT_ADDRESS
*
    10214
    View associated transports

SIB_MQ_ENDPOINT_SECURE_ADDRESS
*
    10215
    View associated transports

SIP_DEFAULTHOST
*
    10216
    View associated transports

SIP_DEFAULTHOST_SECURE
*
    10217
    View associated transports

SOAP_CONNECTOR_ADDRESS
mysite.com
    10205
    No associated transports

WC_adminhost
*
    10201
    View associated transports

WC_adminhost_secure
*
    10203
    View associated transports

WC_defaulthost
*
    10200
    View associated transports

WC_defaulthost_secure
*
    10202
    View associated transports

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Application should be deployed (modules bind) to both application server and web server.

Your web server shown on screen has https 443 and http 80 so:

-make sure application hello is deployed on server and webserver

-ensure you have IHS started,

-generate and propagate IHS plugins

Open application by visiting
https://example.com/hello

By the way 10203 port (usually 9043) is management only.

Answer (score 0):

You can access without IHS also by white listing your host under
*Application servers > server1 > Web container transport chains > WCInboundAdminSecure > TCP inbound channel (TCP_3) > Hostname include list

Answer (score -1):

try to access context of application on  **WC_defaulthost**  or on **WC_defaulthost_secure**  ports i.e 10200(HTTP) or 10202(HTTPS)

Comment: The answer is accurate, if perhaps a bit incomplete.  The application should be available on one of those two mentioned ports (depending on whether security is enabled), for example "myhost.com:10200/hello".

Comment: It is very bad idea accessing application directly via websphere web connector port for anything other than debugging.